# Getting AWS S3 to work with heroku when deploying rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, deployment

I am REALLY having a hard time getting amazon web services S3 storage to be my active record storage solution instead of local in production after deploying to heroku. I get internal server errors in the heroku logs which don't help at all.

my storage.yml

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>


# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
# amazon:
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: "won't show you"
  secret_access_key: "won't show"
  region: "us-east-2"
  bucket: "novay-technologies"
```

production.rb

```
  config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

Made a procfile also since I need to use Puma for a web server in production on Heroku. Don't know if I did that right. From what I understand it's a plain text file with no file extensions like .txt and it's supposed to be in the root directory of your app.

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-production}
```

Gemfile:

```
gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false
```

Anything I'm doing wrong? I also configured the variables on the heroku app for the aws_secret credentials, the bucket name, etc.

Heroku Log:

```
$ heroku logs --tail




    2018-09-14T05:33:47.732692+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:33:47.732579 #12]  INFO -- : [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d] Processing by HomeBlogsController#index as HTML
2018-09-14T05:33:47.756797+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:33:47.756647 #12]  INFO -- : [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d]   Rendering home_blogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-09-14T05:33:47.770155+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:33:47.770028 #12]  INFO -- : [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d]   Rendered home_blogs/_team_slider.html.erb (2.0ms)
2018-09-14T05:33:47.771796+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:33:47.771700 #12]  INFO -- : [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d]   Rendered home_blogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (14.8ms)
2018-09-14T05:33:47.772226+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:33:47.772143 #12]  INFO -- : [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 39ms
2018-09-14T05:33:47.773372+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:33:47.773284 #12] FATAL -- : [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d]
2018-09-14T05:33:47.773494+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:33:47.773397 #12] FATAL -- : [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d] ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "DanielProfile.jpeg" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
2018-09-14T05:33:47.773954+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:33:47.773873 #12] FATAL -- : [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d]     4:     <div id="team-slider">
2018-09-14T05:33:47.773957+00:00 app[web.1]: [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d]     5:
2018-09-14T05:33:47.773959+00:00 app[web.1]: [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d]     6:         <div class="person active" id="person1">
2018-09-14T05:33:47.773960+00:00 app[web.1]: [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d]     7:           <%= image_tag "DanielProfile.jpeg", :id=>"daniel-pic"%>
2018-09-14T05:33:47.773962+00:00 app[web.1]: [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d]     8:           <figcaption><b>Daniel</b></figcaption><p id="bio-text">Info 1</p><br />
2018-09-14T05:33:47.773964+00:00 app[web.1]: [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d]     9:         </div>
2018-09-14T05:33:47.773966+00:00 app[web.1]: [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d]    10:         <div class="person" id="person2">
2018-09-14T05:33:47.773987+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:33:47.773932 #12] FATAL -- : [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d]
2018-09-14T05:33:47.774080+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:33:47.774022 #12] FATAL -- : [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d] app/views/home_blogs/_team_slider.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_home_blogs__team_slider_html_erb__3603015324260213397_47229290931480'
2018-09-14T05:33:47.774083+00:00 app[web.1]: [ff92f910-5fc0-4fcf-895f-d1b3b78b8f2d] app/views/home_blogs/index.html.erb:48:in `_app_views_home_blogs_index_html_erb___3304137320579381618_47229290790300'
2018-09-14T05:33:48.937228+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-chamber-89366.herokuapp.com request_id=5801439c-e276-4837-b2d3-9a071b985f88 fwd="107.77.210.166" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2018-09-14T05:42:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user davidmichaelberko@gmail.com
2018-09-14T05:43:36.124158+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2018-09-14T05:43:36.125133+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2018-09-14T05:43:37.184709+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-09-14T05:43:37.215584+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
2018-09-14T05:43:37.667388+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2018-09-14T05:43:35.147502+00:00 app[api]: Deploy b0e39bae by user davidmichaelberko@gmail.com
2018-09-14T05:43:35.147502+00:00 app[api]: Release v30 created by user davidmichaelberko@gmail.com
2018-09-14T05:43:44.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-09-14T05:43:48.420966+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2018-09-14T05:43:52.242466+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2018-09-14T05:43:52.242489+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.3.5-p376), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2018-09-14T05:43:52.242491+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2018-09-14T05:43:52.242492+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Environment: production
2018-09-14T05:43:52.242494+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Process workers: 2
2018-09-14T05:43:52.242498+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Preloading application
2018-09-14T05:44:03.889732+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:42357
2018-09-14T05:44:03.890105+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] ! WARNING: Detected 1 Thread(s) started in app boot:
2018-09-14T05:44:03.890264+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] ! #<Thread:0x00005645c567a6e0@/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:297 sleep> - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:299:in `sleep'
2018-09-14T05:44:03.890454+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Use Ctrl-C to stop
2018-09-14T05:44:03.937869+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 0 (pid: 8) booted, phase: 0
2018-09-14T05:44:03.961444+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 1 (pid: 10) booted, phase: 0
2018-09-14T05:44:04.216217+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-09-14T05:44:05.299286+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:44:05.299069 #8]  INFO -- : [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df] Started GET "/" for 107.77.210.166 at 2018-09-14 05:44:05 +0000
2018-09-14T05:44:05.310460+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:44:05.310361 #8]  INFO -- : [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df] Processing by HomeBlogsController#index as HTML
2018-09-14T05:44:05.339011+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:44:05.338894 #8]  INFO -- : [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df]   Rendering home_blogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-09-14T05:44:05.351987+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:44:05.351887 #8]  INFO -- : [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df]   Rendered home_blogs/_team_slider.html.erb (1.9ms)
2018-09-14T05:44:05.352439+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:44:05.352370 #8]  INFO -- : [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df]   Rendered home_blogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (13.2ms)
2018-09-14T05:44:05.353290+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:44:05.353183 #8]  INFO -- : [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 40ms
2018-09-14T05:44:05.355779+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:44:05.355705 #8] FATAL -- : [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df]
2018-09-14T05:44:05.355917+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:44:05.355854 #8] FATAL -- : [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df] ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "DanielProfile.jpeg" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
2018-09-14T05:44:05.356321+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:44:05.356268 #8] FATAL -- : [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df]     4:     <div id="team-slider">
2018-09-14T05:44:05.356338+00:00 app[web.1]: [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df]     5:
2018-09-14T05:44:05.356340+00:00 app[web.1]: [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df]     6:         <div class="person active" id="person1">
2018-09-14T05:44:05.356342+00:00 app[web.1]: [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df]     7:           <%= image_tag "DanielProfile.jpeg", :id=>"daniel-pic"%>
2018-09-14T05:44:05.356343+00:00 app[web.1]: [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df]     8:           <figcaption><b>Daniel</b></figcaption><p id="bio-text">Info 1</p><br />
2018-09-14T05:44:05.356345+00:00 app[web.1]: [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df]     9:         </div>
2018-09-14T05:44:05.356346+00:00 app[web.1]: [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df]    10:         <div class="person" id="person2">
2018-09-14T05:44:05.356602+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:44:05.356549 #8] FATAL -- : [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df]
2018-09-14T05:44:05.356712+00:00 app[web.1]: [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df] app/views/home_blogs/index.html.erb:48:in `_app_views_home_blogs_index_html_erb___3107958943898777696_47428845125780'
2018-09-14T05:44:05.356710+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:44:05.356640 #8] FATAL -- : [b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df] app/views/home_blogs/_team_slider.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_home_blogs__team_slider_html_erb___1927171972031439227_47428845168680'
2018-09-14T05:44:05.358493+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=boiling-chamber-89366.herokuapp.com request_id=b6f95d3c-9886-456d-8be6-a2c3182228df fwd="107.77.210.166" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=65ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2018-09-14T05:44:06.613224+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-chamber-89366.herokuapp.com request_id=e5ed5731-f771-4ab7-afbf-3e7f2d86d85c fwd="107.77.210.166" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
2018-09-14T05:45:04.903443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2018-09-14T05:45:04.905478+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2018-09-14T05:45:06.313295+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-09-14T05:45:06.335333+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
2018-09-14T05:45:07.214828+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2018-09-14T05:45:17.193313+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2018-09-14T05:45:20.580532+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2018-09-14T05:45:20.580563+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.3.5-p376), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2018-09-14T05:45:20.580564+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2018-09-14T05:45:20.580566+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Environment: production
2018-09-14T05:45:20.580567+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Process workers: 2
2018-09-14T05:45:20.580569+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Preloading application
2018-09-14T05:45:32.131340+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:53222
2018-09-14T05:45:32.131751+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] ! WARNING: Detected 1 Thread(s) started in app boot:
2018-09-14T05:45:32.131894+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] ! #<Thread:0x0000556669fe6350@/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:297 sleep> - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:299:in `sleep'
2018-09-14T05:45:32.132083+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Use Ctrl-C to stop
2018-09-14T05:45:32.154305+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 1 (pid: 10) booted, phase: 0
2018-09-14T05:45:32.157217+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 0 (pid: 8) booted, phase: 0
2018-09-14T05:45:32.833157+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-09-14T05:45:35.047364+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:45:35.047164 #8]  INFO -- : [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad] Started GET "/" for 107.77.210.166 at 2018-09-14 05:45:35 +0000
2018-09-14T05:45:35.060284+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:45:35.060154 #8]  INFO -- : [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad] Processing by HomeBlogsController#index as HTML
2018-09-14T05:45:35.088955+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:45:35.088816 #8]  INFO -- : [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad]   Rendering home_blogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-09-14T05:45:35.101253+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:45:35.101109 #8]  INFO -- : [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad]   Rendered home_blogs/_team_slider.html.erb (2.7ms)
2018-09-14T05:45:35.101556+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:45:35.101475 #8]  INFO -- : [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad]   Rendered home_blogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.3ms)
2018-09-14T05:45:35.102302+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-14T05:45:35.102231 #8]  INFO -- : [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 41ms
2018-09-14T05:45:35.104595+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:45:35.104479 #8] FATAL -- : [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad]
2018-09-14T05:45:35.104745+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:45:35.104653 #8] FATAL -- : [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad] ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "DanielProfile.jpeg" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
2018-09-14T05:45:35.105338+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:45:35.105220 #8] FATAL -- : [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad]     4:     <div id="team-slider">
2018-09-14T05:45:35.105341+00:00 app[web.1]: [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad]     5:
2018-09-14T05:45:35.105343+00:00 app[web.1]: [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad]     6:         <div class="person active" id="person1">
2018-09-14T05:45:35.105347+00:00 app[web.1]: [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad]     7:           <%= image_tag "DanielProfile.jpeg", :id=>"daniel-pic"%>
2018-09-14T05:45:35.105349+00:00 app[web.1]: [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad]     8:           <figcaption><b>Daniel</b></figcaption><p id="bio-text">Info 1</p><br />
2018-09-14T05:45:35.105352+00:00 app[web.1]: [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad]     9:         </div>
2018-09-14T05:45:35.105354+00:00 app[web.1]: [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad]    10:         <div class="person" id="person2">
2018-09-14T05:45:35.105462+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:45:35.105380 #8] FATAL -- : [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad]
2018-09-14T05:45:35.105578+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-14T05:45:35.105512 #8] FATAL -- : [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad] app/views/home_blogs/_team_slider.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_home_blogs__team_slider_html_erb___49138702036072628_46949189469860'
2018-09-14T05:45:35.105582+00:00 app[web.1]: [3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad] app/views/home_blogs/index.html.erb:48:in `_app_views_home_blogs_index_html_erb__3183323660226002528_46949189328600'
2018-09-14T05:45:35.110118+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=boiling-chamber-89366.herokuapp.com request_id=3e50fd37-83b8-4d42-a369-6b03c7d87cad fwd="107.77.210.166" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=67ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2018-09-14T05:45:35.913068+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-chamber-89366.herokuapp.com request_id=cdfbccd2-efcf-4a1a-8c9e-849d05efa8fd fwd="107.77.210.166" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
 ▸    Log stream timed out. Please try again.
```

puma.rb

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.3.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'devise'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.11.1'


gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'tinymce-rails-imageupload', github: 'PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload'
gem 'will_paginate'

gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'fog'

gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

gem 'pg'
gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Is `puma` running, did you check the logs ? Can you also post the `logs` ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna just posted the logs. Hope that sheds some light!

Comment: Well according to logs, `puma` is not running, it seems to fail. Do you have `puma` in your `Gemfile` ? Can you also share `puma.rb` ?

Comment: Do you see this error ? `ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "DanielProfile.jpeg" is not present in the asset pipeline.)`

Comment: Yeah, I saw the missing asset error. I think the problem problem lies in my puma.rb file though which I will post the code to above. See what you think

Comment: Can you try running this `heroku config:set "BUNDLE_DISABLE_EXEC_LOAD"="true"` in heroku cli ?

Comment: It didn't fix it. If you'd like I'll copy and paste the new logs

Comment: Yes please, can you update the new logs ?

Comment: They're updated. Haven't changed much from the last one unfortunately. I really doubt getting rid of one picture which as it turns out actually is in my asset pipeline in the images directory would change things

Comment: Can you restart the dyno `heroku ps:restart`.

Comment: Wish that would've done the trick. Stil not resolving it. I updated the log again. :/ It's been a long day working on this lol. I'm going to have to research puma and heroku more.

Comment: I don't see it as an issue with `puma`.

Comment: Can you also share your `Gemfile` ? btw what version of `Rails` and `Ruby` are you using ?

Comment: I have rails 5.2 and ruby 2.3.5. I had to move to stack cedar-14 which is deprecated because when I would try to deploy to heroku it kept trying to bundle version 2.3.7 even though in my gemfile and gemfile lock it was specified to 2.3.5 which is the last supported ruby version for heroku.

Comment: In your Procfile, can you remove the `port` and `environment`, as it is already defined in `puma.rb`. You're line in `Procfile`, should look like this now `web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`

Comment: Why is puma command being searched in `ruby/2.3.0`? you're using `2.3.5`. Have you set the version of `ruby` ?

Comment: Good question. I really did think that the change to the procfile was the solution but sadly there's more to this riddle.

Comment: Can you check on heroku what version of Ruby is being used ? `heroku run 'ruby -v'`

Comment: heroku run 'ruby -v'
Running ruby -v on ⬢ boiling-chamber-89366... up, run.6474 (Free)
ruby 2.3.5p376 (2017-09-14 revision 59905) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: I don't see this error anymore in the new logs `bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma)`. Do you see it ?

Comment: No I don't. Changing the exec command in the procfile to point to the puma config file fixed that error which is great

Comment: Ok, now fix the `Completed 500 Internal Server Error`. One of the assets is missing `ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "DanielProfile.jpeg" is not present in the asset pipeline.)`, can you fix that ?

Comment: Awesome! You saved my day. I fixed the other errors. But the Puma one I don't know if I could've done without your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-production}
```

puma.rb

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

The problem was the environment and port are already defined in `puma.rb`, and it need not be defined again in the `Procfile`. Hence the `Procfile` should look something like this

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```